# Can't upload video form wysiwyg

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg, upload, tinymce, video

After clicking insert/edit embedded media in the editor (wysiwyg) in magento admin, appears an error in my console. Indeed I can upload a video, but I can't insert it to my page. it says :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
>
> editor_plugin_src.js

[image]

FYI im using magento 2.2.9 upgraded from 2.1.7, in nginx environment, and im using `pub` directory for docroot following this article https://support.hypernode.com/knowledgebase/installing-magento-2-on-hypernode/

Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you tried inserting outside of the wysiwyg `<video id="myVideo" width="100%" height="300px" autoplay="autoplay" muted="" loop="loop">
<source src="{{view url="/pub/media/movies/movie.mp4"}}" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>`

Comment: hi dominic, thank you for your response. yes Ive tried to insert that directly without wysiwyg. however the error still appearing when we open / edit page in magento admin like this [link](http://prntscr.com/ojwgzq) . more over, we cant just insert html code for our client, he cant do that. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Does seem to be more an issue with wysiwy.  You could try updating the wysiwyg https://github.com/pavelleonidov/magento2-tinymce4 Try on dev site first.  Beyond that I don't know sorry.

Comment: it works, thank you! I just think to update tinymce before, but not sure which module it is. you saved my day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll put as answer.

Does seem to be more an issue with wysiwyg.

You could try updating the wysiwyg http://github.com/pavelleonidov/magento2-tinymce4

Try on dev site first.